# SQL filter result to current month and previous two months

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my sql code:

```
SELECT  Month   = datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)), 
Cast ((ROUND(((CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(Duration)/60)/60)),2)*55) AS numeric(36,2)) 
FROM VExecutionGlobalHistory Where Tester <> 'dit2988' AND TestTypeID = 1 

group by dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)) 
order by dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0))
```

This query returns:

```
April|123
  May|3456
 June|856
 July|345
```

I want it to return the following:

```
  May|3456
 June|856
 July|345
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2010

Comment: Can you include input data?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: StartTime -column1
2013-04-01 12:39:56.000
EndTime -column2
2013-04-01 12:44:42.000
Duration -column3
286

Comment: Just added RDBMS to bottom

Comment: I tagged your question with 'sql-server'

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2010 ? Maybe Visual Studio 2010 or SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return the first day of the month, 2 months back from today:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0)AS DATE)
```

So you can add to your `WHERE` criteria:

```
SELECT  Month   = datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)), 
Cast ((ROUND(((CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(Duration)/60)/60)),2)*55) AS numeric(36,2)) 
FROM VExecutionGlobalHistory 
Where Tester <> 'dit2988' AND TestTypeID = 1 
      AND StartTime >= CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0) AS DATE)
group by dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)) 
order by dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 12 b.Month, b.Amount
FROM
(
      SELECT TOP 12 a.Year, a.SortMonth, a.Month, a.Amount
  FROM
  (
        SELECT 
              Year = datename(Year,StartTime),
              SortMonth = month(StartTime),
              Month = datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)), 
              Amount = Cast ((ROUND(((CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),SUM(Duration)/60)/60)),2)*55) AS numeric(36,2))
        FROM VExecutionGlobalHistory 
        Where Tester <> 'dit2988' 
          AND TestTypeID = 1 

        group by
              datename(Year,StartTime),
              month(StartTime),
              dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), 
              year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0))
  ) a
  ORDER BY a.Year, a.SortMonth DESC
) b
ORDER BY b.Year, b.SortMonth
```

Comment: Any more efficient way than above?